# Using Filter based query parameters using Azure Graph API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, python-requests, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using MSAL Graph API to retrieve data from the Azure AD. Since i wanted specific information i am trying to use $filter that you can pass as parameters. But since $filter accepts AND/OR clause i tried to fetch info by passing multiple values such as follows

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id = patclientid,
                                authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID",
                                client_credential = patclient_credential)

parameters = {'$filter':'createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18 and appDisplayName eq appName'}

if "access_token" in result:
print(result['access_token'])
user_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns",
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
    params=parameters).json()
```

On running above it gave me following error

```
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
```

I have tried the same request in POSTMAN and it worked fine. But it somehow is not working in python.

Comment: Could you please do encode for the $filter query before add the $filter query in the request ?

Comment: Did q=urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters) and passed it to get requests. Still didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I noticed you use `$filter : created....` but not `$filter=....`. So could you please just do encode for `createdDateTime ge 2020.......` but not all of the parameters ? Because encode the parameters will also do encode for the `:` character.

Comment: Ok. i did q=urllib.parse.urlencode('createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18')
parameters = {'$filter':q} and then passed parameters in the request. Still failed.

Comment: But please note  when i send this parameters = {'$filter':'createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18'} to requests it passes successfully. So encode is not required for this. Its only when i add "and" it causing problems

Comment: Ok, I have reproduce your problem in explorer, it was caused by missing `"`. Could you please add another `'` pair or `"` pair to wrap around the `appName`. Like `'$filter':'createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18 and appDisplayName eq "appName"'`, or use `\'`(or `\"`) to escape.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I used parameters = {'$filter':'createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18 and appDisplayName eq \'OFSC \' '}

Comment: Great, could you please mark the solution I provided below as "accepted", thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by missing `"`(`'`) character, just use:

```
parameters = {'$filter':'createdDateTime ge 2020-06-18 and appDisplayName eq \'OFSC \' '}
```